# Facebooker Rails plugin - Notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, publisher

I have quite silly question: how to send notifications?
For example, when I register user on my app, I want to welcome him/her with 
notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Facebooker (which, really, you should be), you can create a [Publisher class](http://apps.facebook.com/facebooker_tutorial/messaging/mini_feed).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use facebook_session.send_notification([user_fb_id], "notification message") (in your controller). This will be an app-to-user notification, and you have a limited number that you can send to users each week.

To see this limit you can use the following call:
Facebooker::Session.create.post('facebook.admin.getAllocation', :integration_point_name => 'announcement_notifications_per_week')